# Jbehave pass data in lifecycle step

Tags: jbehave, jbehave-plugin

in below example data is being passed in scenario steps, but not in Lifecycle step any idea why?

```
Lifecycle:
Before:
Scope: SCENARIO|STORY
Outcome: ANY

When I enter search criteria (<ProfilerEntityName>) on the Search page

Given I navigate to CB Finder
When I select file with Name (<FileName>)
When I delete the file which is currently selected

Scenario: Basic report functionality

When I enter search criteria (<ProfilerEntityName>) on the Search page

Given I navigate to CB Finder
When I select file with Name (<FileName>)
When I delete file which is currently selected

Examples:
| ProfilerEntityName |FileName   |                      
|*              |sha|Call |
```

Comment: I see many potential problems.  Your Scenarios need to be in Given/When/Then format, in that order.  Your examples table does not match up: two header columns, three data columns.  As to the the lifecycle aspect, I have no experience to offer any help there.

Comment: Thanks, we can have scenarios in any format there is no rule that it should be Given/When/Then format.